# ReferenceError: DocumentReader is not defined NODE JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have this class called DocumentReader in a "/lib/DocumentReader.js" i tried to export it using `module.exports = DocumentReader;` and i have another file called `main.js` that i'm trying to use this file in it but when ever i do this

```
var doc = require("./lib/DocumentReader.js");
var docr = new DocumentReader("");
```

i get this error `ReferenceError: DocumentReader is not defined`

this is the class in  DocumentReader.js

```
var fs = require("fs");
class DocumentReader{
    constructor (filepath){
        this.filepath = filepath;
    }

     readfile(){

        fs.readFile(this.filepath,function(err,data){
                if(err) throw err;

            console.log(data);
        });
    }

}
```

i tried looking for similiar errors or cases like this but i didn't find them

when i print the value of `doc` i get this `[Function: DocumentReader]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `require` something you need to call `new` on the variable that it was assigned to via `require`. `DocumentReader` doesn't exist because you haven't declared `DocumentReader` in your file requiring `lib/DocumentReader`.

`module.exports` only exports the reference to `class DocumentReader` which is a function with the name `DocumentReader`. This is why when you use `console.log(doc)` you're still seeing `[Function: DocumentReader]` printed out.

```
const DocumentReader = require('./lib/DocumentReader')
const docr = new DocumentReader('')
```